# MDX Default values hierarchys

Tags: mdx, hierarchy, pentaho

I am trying to parameterize an `MDX` query in a reporting tool (Pentaho Report Designer) and only want to pass the year and month number. I will need to somehow default the quarter, month name, mon abbreviation based on the last member of the hierarchy which is the month number (6). Is this possible in `MDX`?
Creating a separate hierarchy with just year and month number may not work in this case.

code is:

```
[Accounting Period].CURRENTMEMBER IN {[Accounting Period].[2014].[2].[June].[Jun].[6]}
```

Comment: Strange dialect: is this code extracted from Pentaho?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can play with `membervalue`'s or `memberkey`'s. Against AdvWks we can run this as an illustration:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER MEASURES.VALUE_DEMO AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  MEMBER MEASURES.KEY_DEMO AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,MEASURES.VALUE_DEMO
   ,MEASURES.KEY_DEMO
  } ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This is A snippet of what it returns:

[image]

Then you could start applying `VBA` functions to extract bits of these measures e.g. the `LEFT` 4 characters from the key:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER MEASURES.VALUE_DEMO AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  MEMBER MEASURES.KEY_DEMO AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER MEASURES.KEY_DEMO_LEFT AS 
    VBA!Left
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Key
     ,4
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,MEASURES.VALUE_DEMO
   ,MEASURES.KEY_DEMO
   ,MEASURES.KEY_DEMO_LEFT
  } ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```